# Using an instance of a Python object from a Java code

Tags: python, java, oop

I'm trying to integrate my Python backend program into a project that's predominantly written in Java, and I was wondering if there is any way I could create, "maintain", and call a certain Python object from Java code.
In particular: I have a "Head" class in my Python code that contains a bunch of useful methods I'd like to call and get their output from a Java code. A solution to this would be to write a script that instantiates and runs methods in "Head" every time it's necessary. The problem is, however, that Head takes a lot of time to instantiate (I have to load some models, etc.), and therefore it would be much more time-effective to keep it running in the background. Is this by any chance possible? Or am I just thinking of something that is not possible to do in a reasonable way? I couldn't find anything helpful on the internet. Thank you.

Comment: There are two basic ways of approaching it: a. use a dedicated bridging api such as Jython or b. use text-based IO into/out of your Python class using something like `ProcessBuilder`

Comment: @g00se oh, I have heard of Jython before, but I didn't think it's capable of "keeping" an instantiated python object and call its methods.

Comment: Well I'm no expert on [Jython](https://www.jython.org/) but I think it will give you some degree of Integration

Comment: You can just wrap your object in a small [flask app](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) (or whatever microframework you prefer) and then just query it from your Java process